# Import Mantaflow VDB Cache Files into Bleder doesn´t work correctly

Tags: import, smoke-simulation, volumetrics, mantaflow

I made a Smoke Simulation with Mantaflow and then tried to import the vdb files from the data folder in the cache folder, but the imported vdb sequence doesn´t look the same. It looks simplistic and is much shorter in length. The left smoke is the correct Mantaflow smoke and the right is the imported VDB sequence in the picture. Noise is also activated for the simulation. Can it be related? In the cache folder there is also a noise folder with a VDB sequence, but nothing is shown with this files, only the outline of the sequence.

[image]

What can i do here?

Answer (score 1):

I´ve now found it out. You first have to load the vdb files in the data and the noise folder from the cache folder seperately. And in the material settings of the noise volume you have to write "density_noise" in the Density Attribut of the Volume Node. Then the noise is also shown. Then you can parent the two volumes so that they are always together.